# Receiving the same error when running query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

I have tried to query a piece of code in Oracle, but I continue to receive the error ORA 00933. Can anyone point me to the solution?
This is the piece of code:

```
SELECT 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM i.invoicedate) AS Month
      , CAST(i.invoicedate AS DATE) AS Invoicedate
      , I.fiscalinvoiceid
      , I.invoiceid
      , NULL as Quantity
      , I.shipmentcost AS Invoiceprice
      , CASE WHEn I.creditinvoiceid IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * ROUND((I.shipmentcost * 
      CASE WHEN I.vatfree = 'N' THEN (1+ (V.vatpercentage / 100)) ELSE 1 END), 2) as 'Total'
      , I.vatfree
      , creditinvoiceid
      , 'Shipment' AS costtype
      , I.customerid
      , I.subsidiaryid
      , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM I.paymentduedate) AS dueyear
      , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM I.paymentduedate) AS duemonth
      , I.paymentmethodid  
    FROM VAN_Invoice I
    INNER JOIN VAN_VAT V ON I.shipmentcostvatid = V.vatid
```

Comment: Do you know all error codes by heart? I don't, please provide the actual error message

Comment: `as 'Total'` is wrong, should be `as "Total"`or `as Total`

Comment: Sorry, but even without reading your post - just from your title and the first line in your post, I get the impression that you believe that Oracle should throw different errors at different times, even when you run the same code. Your complaint seems to be that the code keeps throwing the same error, no matter how many times you try to run it. Is that the main issue? That's the first impression I got, anyway.

Comment: This is very easy to debug. Remove all columns from the query apart from the first one. Run it. If you don't get the error, add next column and run it again. At some point you'll get the error and you'll know which line is causing it. Then look for the syntax error and thats it.